# How to calculate Distance $D$ to object from a camera with known $H$?

Tags: optics, geometry, vision, camera, computer

I am using algorithm to draw a bounding box around object when they appear in camera as shown in attached image. The main confusion is that i consider the object closer to camera when the Distance $D$ in pixels (red line) is less than $p$ (pixels) (say 10px). This is working well in practice, can some one explain, how can i convert the pixel p to actual distance in world units.

[image: Camera image of dog with bounding box]

I have all the calibration values for my camera and object size is known.

**Please note:**

- it is important to use $D$ as distance because in some cases when the object is very close, the $D$ is 0.
- Even if the height of dog is changed, $D$ still remains the same if dog is placed the same position

Comment: I don't think that this is possible with a photo, apart from using AI

Comment: Considering H is known, should it be possible using FOV and mm/px conversions?

Comment: The thing is, is that dog, could be massive, but far away  and small but close. Only using the background, can we determine its true size. And the only way we can use the background is because we as humans know what the background is. I believe this is only possible with AI. However, I could be wrong, as I know there are apps that allow you to build things in 3d augmented reality. But I would assume they also use AI

Comment: The real size of dog is already known. In my practical experiments i have placed objects of known size.